# Replace composer package in framework by other fork

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I use a composer-driven framework (Laravel 4).
It uses Carbon class for datetime-operations. Carbon provides perfect things, but leaks some features that I need.
So, I've forked it, written new feature, pushed it in my repo on GitHub.

Question is how to make composer replace Carbon from original repo, at which framework's composer.json links, on my version?

In root composer.json I've added link to my repo:

```
"repositories":[
    ...
    {
        "type":"git",
        "url":"https://github.com/terion-name/Carbon"
    }
],
```

Also I've tried to add "nesbot/carbon": "*" in "require" block, I've tried to add

```
"replace" : {
  "nesbot/carbon": "self.version"
},
```

In my version of Carbon composer.json.
Nothing works.
Composer installs original version of carbon, not paying attention at my repo

Answer (score 0):

Composer by default reads from `packagist.org`.

Since you have forked a repo on github, you can expose that fork to packagist so Composer can read from it the same way.

Comment: It is not entirely true. Composer can read packages from packagist.org, github.com, any other git repo or even from links on zip-archives. To do so, you should just add additional repos in "repositories" section of composer.json file.

Comment: @ВладимирКорнилов I know, but since it is a Github fork, it makes sense to add it to packagist if you are using composer.

Answer (score 0):

```
"repositories": [
    { "packagist": false },
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://local/packages.json"
    }
]
```